# taking time when going from one activity to another by button click

Tags: android

When I am going from one activity to another by button click, in my second activity I am displaying an advertisement in webview in the top position. It is coming from a url so it takes time to navigate to another activity, so I want to ask: is there any solution for do it after i navigate to next activity and then download of image begins.

In `on create`, I wrote this code:

```
     SharedPreferences BannerPrefs = getSharedPreferences("BannerPref", 0);
     BannerLink = BannerPrefs.getString("BannerLink", "");
     BannerUrl = BannerPrefs.getString("BannerUrl", "");
     WebView wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.imv);
     wv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {



     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final Intent intent = new                  Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(BannerLink));
        startActivity(intent);          
        return false;
     }
     });
     wv.loadUrl(BannerUrl);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you should use `thread` to fetch data and as soon as you get it update it using `Handler` ..You can use `AsyncTask` for this.

for AsyncTask refer this doc:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html